# Why does stat_summary produce error bars only when numbers are in y, not x?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to wrap my head around how `stat_summary` works, because I'd like to use it to add error bars to a plot that includes all the individual data points.  Here's what I don't understand:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Species)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), size = 4)
```

produces the type of plot I want:

[image: plot with error bars]

But if I try to make the plot with Sepal.Length on the x axis instead of the y axis, no error bars:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), size = 4)
```

[image: Imgur]

I know I can fix my problem by simply adding `+ coord_flip()` to the first plot, but I'd really like to understand how `stat_summary` works, why it is sensitive to whether the data are on the x or y axis, and how to tell it that I've done something other than what it expects.

Also, I'd really like to be able to use `facet_wrap(~Factor, scales = "free")` to plot my real data, but that doesn't work (`Error in facet_render.wrap(plot$facet, panel, plot$coordinates, plot_theme(plot),  : ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.`)

Can anyone explain why `stat_summary` is sensitive to which axis the numbers are on, and whether there's a way to tell it that my data are in a format other than its default?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at `geom_errorbar`. Under "Aesthetics" you find `x`, `ymin`, `ymax`. You don't find `y`, `xmin`, `xmax`. So, horizontal error bars are not possible without flipping the axes.

Answer (score 2):

The title on the help page of `stat_summary()` already states that this function `Summarise y values at every unique x`. So if you set y values as `Species` and `Sepal.Length` as x, function will try to summarize `Species` at each unique x values (this doesn't work because `Species` isn't numeric and confidence interval can't be calculated).

If you would set another function inside the `stat_summary()`, for example, `fun.y=length` then you can see that for each unique x value number of observation will be calculated (this function works also on factors and character vectors).

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = length, geom = "point", size=10)+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), size = 4)
```

Comment: OK, I'm with you.  So I need to figure out if there is a function (or combination of functions) that work on factors that will yield the calculation I want.  Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to calculate confidence intervals before plotting and then plot summarized data. In this case you can use geom_errorbarh() (h letter at end) that plots horizontal error bars.